# Does continuous and strictly increasing implies convex function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a continous and strictly monotone increasing function and $f(0)=0$. Then prove or disprove that $f$ is a convex function.

My initial guess that, $f$ is a convex function, I want to prove it.

I am unable to proceed!I'm not getting any idea how to use continuity. Any hint?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=\sqrt x$ are both continuous and strictly monotone. But one is convex and the other is concave.

Comment: Wouldn't $f(x) = \sqrt x$ disprove this?

Comment: $x+\sin(x)$ alternates concave, convex, concave, convex,....

Comment: $f(x)=1-{1 \over 1+x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take
$$
f(x) = \log(1+x)
$$
Then $f(0)=0$, $f'(x) = 1/(1+x)>0$, but $f''<0$, so $f$ is concave but satisfies all the hypotheses.